# Size of downloaded jpeg- R

Tags: r, image, jpeg

I'm using the following code (and getting the following outputs) when I try to download a jpeg file from a url. I want to find out the size of the file (ex: In this case, 211 KB)

> url="http://www.willswildanimalencounters.com/www/images/aph.jpg"
>
> z <- tempfile()
>
> b=download.file(url,z,mode="wb")
>
> > trying URL 'http://www.willswildanimalencounters.com/www/images/aph.jpg'
> >     Content type 'image/jpeg' **length 216799 bytes (211 KB)
> >     downloaded 211 KB**
>
> object.size(b)
>
> > 48 bytes
>
> pic <- readJPEG(z, native = TRUE)
>
> object.size(z)
>
> > 136 bytes

I'm trying to get the bolded information, the size of the downloaded image that it displays when downloading the image, but I'm only able to get answers of 48 or 136 bytes using object.size() regardless of the URL I use.

Any suggestions on how to access that 211KB piece of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file_size <- file.info(z)$size
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! I wasn't aware of the file.size() function and it wasn't appearing on Google searches either.